# writing to plist but it's empty when I quit simulation

Tags: iphone, xcode, plist

Hi I implemented this object PlistManager to write/read plist in my project.The problem is that the plist is populated fine will running (I hope) and when entering in background (I used notification and NSlog the [Plistmanager readPlist:@"Database"]) i still can read the data entered before.

**The point is when I stop the simulation on xcode and run again the plist is now empty. Why?**

```
@interface ReadWritePlist : NSObject
+(void)writeToPlist:(NSString*)filePlist dic:(NSDictionary*)dic;
+ (NSMutableDictionary *)readPlist:(NSString*)filePlist;

@end

@implementation ReadWritePlist


+ (void)writeToPlist:(NSString*)filePlist dic:(NSDictionary*)dic
{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    [dic writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist",filePlist]] atomically:YES];

}


+ (NSMutableDictionary *)readPlist:(NSString*)filePlist {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePlist] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    return dic;
}
```

**solved**

I just found these new methods for read/write plist and it is working.I had to add the "initializeFileDic" method inside appdelegate (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions):

```
@implementation PlistManager

+ (NSMutableDictionary *)readPlist:(NSString*)filePlist {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePlist] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

return dic;
}




+ (void)writeToPlist:(NSString*)filePlist dic:(NSDictionary*)dic
{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    if ([dic writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist",filePlist]] atomically:YES]) {
    NSLog(@"Ok done!");
    } 
    else{
            NSLog(@"Noo not done!");
    }
} 

+ (void)initializeFileDic:(NSString*)FileNameExt
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString *startPath = [[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:FileNameExt]stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"plist"] ;
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [[documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:FileNameExt]stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"plist"];

    NSLog(@"%@ \n,\n %@ ",startPath,filePath);
    if([NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: startPath]){
    NSLog(@"File %@ exists",filePath);
    }
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]){
        if([[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:startPath] writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO])
        NSLog(@"File copied inside App DocumentsDirectory\n\n");
    else
        NSLog(@"Error while trying to copy into DocumentsDirectory\n\n"); 
    }

}


@end
```

Could Anybody explain what was wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Did you know `NSDictionary`'s [writeToFile method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/writeToFile:atomically:) returns a success result?  Check to see if it is YES or NO.  Also, what kinds of things are you keeping track of in your dictionary?  Are any of these items custom Objective C objects?

Answer (score 0):

When do you make the call to save the data to the plist? If you quit your app from Xcode then it is terminated immediately, and doesn't go through any of the application delegate methods related to terminating or entering the background, which is where I suspect your code is.

Pressing the home button on the simulator is the way to get those methods to run.